# How to add new text to the textarea without deleting the older one when an event triggers using js for example clicking button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is a simple cart add program. If I click the Add button I need to add the selected content on the text area but when I add the second item my first item was deleted and my text area is reset and my second content is displayed how to avoid that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>Chapter 10, Temp</title>
        <style>
        p{
            padding:0;
            margin:15px 0 0 0;
        }
        ul{
        list-style: none;

            margin:0;   
        }
        #listing{
            float:left;
            width:40%;
            background-color:#CCFFFF;
        }
        #CartView{
            margin-left:45%;
            width:18%;
            background-color:#99ff99;
            position: fixed;
        }
        #deliverPage{
            position: fixed;
            width:18%;
            background-color:#E0E0E0;
            margin-left:70%;
        
        }
        </style>
        </head>


        <body>

        
            <form name="myForm">
            <div id="listing">
            <div id="pCoreType">
            <p><label for="cpu"> Select the Processor Core : </label></p>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="coreType" value ="Core2Duo" /><label>Core2Duo - Rs.3500/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="coreType" value ="I3" /><label>I3 - Rs.5000/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="coreType" value ="I5" /><label>I5 - Rs.7500/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="coreType" value ="I7" /><label>I7 - Rs.9500/-</label></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Add To Cart" name="pCoreAdd"/>
            </div>

            <div id="motherBoard">
            <p><label for="MB"> Select the MotherBoard Model: </label></p>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="mbModel" value ="Intel" /><label>Intel - Rs.3500/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="mbModel" value ="Asus" /><label>Asus - Rs.3900/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="mbModel" value ="GigaByte" /><label>GigaByte - Rs.3700/-</label></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="mbModel" value ="FoxConn" /><label>FoxConn - Rs.4500/-</label></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Add To Cart" name="mbModelAdd"/>
            </div>

            </div>
        
        
            <div id="CartView">
            Cart: <input type="button" value="CheckOut" name="checkOut"/><br/>
            <textarea name="cartDetails" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="deliverPage">
            CheckOuts <br />
            Your Order Total Cost is :
            <input type="text" name="orderTotal"/>

            </div>
            </form>
            

            <script>

            var myForm = document.myForm;
            var CartView = myForm.cartDetails;
            var CheckOuts = document.getElementById("deliverPage");
            var totalCost =[];


            function pCoreType(){
                var radios = myForm.coreType;
                var corePrice = ["3500","5000","7500","9500"];

            for(var index = 0; index < radios.length; index++){
                    if(radios[index].checked){
                        var ItemSelected = radios[index].value;
                        var price = parseInt(corePrice[index],10);
                        totalCost.push(price);
                        CartView.value = "Processor - " + ItemSelected + " - Rs."+ price ;

                    }
                }
                

            }
            function mbModel(){
                var radios = myForm.coreType;
                var corePrice = ["3500","3900","3700","4500"];
                for(var index = 0; index < radios.length; index++){
                    if(radios[index].checked){
                        var ItemSelected = radios[index].value;
                        var price = parseInt(corePrice[index],10);
                        totalCost.push(price);
                        CartView.value = "\nMotherBoard - " + ItemSelected + " - Rs."+ price;
                    }
                }


            }
        myForm.pCoreAdd.addEventListener("click",pCoreType);
        myForm.mbModelAdd.addEventListener("click",mbModel);
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify

`CartView.value =someValue`   to `CartView.value += someValue`

Verify it from [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wtru2m07/)

Also I feel the above code be modified and same thing can be acheived with less lines of code

Comment: Thanks a lot, guide me the other way if you're free. I'll be really happy

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to save the 1st one as a variable, then add it to the second content.

```
 var content = document.getElementById(CartView).value;
 CartView.value = content + " \n Processor - " + ItemSelected + " - Rs."+ price ;
```